# Add parents to a course offering via Valence

Tags: desire2learn, valence

According to the Valence documentation there doesn't seem to be a way to add parents to a course offering via Valence.  I see that the [Course.CreateCourseOffering](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/course.html#Course.CreateCourseOffering) doesn't have options for parents nor does it's [Course.CourseOfferingInfo](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/course.html#Course.CourseOfferingInfo) used for updating a course offering.  For the [Course.CreateCourseTemplate](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/course.html#Course.CreateCourseTemplate) there is an option for parents.  I also see that with OrgUnits there are options for this with [structure](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#structure), but I don't see anything for Course Offerings.

The Org Unit Editor in D2L itself does allow me to add parents to a course offering, but I would like to do so through Valence.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add parents or children to an arbitrary org unit (including course offerings) with one of:

- http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#post--d2l-api-lp-(version)-orgstructure-(orgUnitId)-children-
- http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#post--d2l-api-lp-(version)-orgstructure-(orgUnitId)-parents-

You still need to create the other org unit or have it created already before calling one of these.

Comment: Jeff is correct; keep in mind that a Course Offering org unit must, I believe, have at least one Course Template as a parent. In effect, when you create a course through the "create course" API call, the `CourseTemplateId` you provide is the parent for the new course. This means that you can't delete the last Course Template parent from a course offering. It's also possible that having more than one Course Template as a parent for a Course Offering may be problematic (owing to how/when things get inherited from template to course), but I'm not sure about that.